# Adding psql data source to fresh Grafana install

Tags: grafana

I am doing a fresh grafana install. I am trying to add PSQL data source to it, and going through Data Sources / PostgreSQL. I have provided host (localhost), database, user and password, and I know that database is up and running because I can connect with `psql` command.

However, when I click `Save & Test`, I am presented with a big red banner which reads `Metric request error`.

Grafana log tells me that

> EROR[03-26|14:49:31] Metric request error
>   logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="dbname is empty"
>
> EROR[03-26|14:49:31] Request Completed
>   logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=POST
>   path=/api/tsdb/query status=500 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=12 size=34
>   referer=http://localhost:3000/datasources/edit/1/

Which is not very helpful. I can post a screenshot if one thinks it can be useful. How do I troubleshoot it? Which direction should I look?

Here is a screenshot of UI:

[image: Grafana screenshot]

Comment: For the record, I was able to add the source successfully using yaml-based provisioning. Still curious why UI method failed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must explicitly set the Host url, the faded text value of "localhost:5432" is not actually being used by Grafana.. This is unintuitive since the other four faded values are fine to leave as they are!

Answer (score -1):

> error="dbname is empty"

Probably you didn't specify DB name datasource configuration in the UI properly.  Screenshot of datasource configuration will be useful here.

Comment: Screenshot added, looks like database is still there?

Comment: @SergeyA Are you able to run `SELECT 1` (SQL for datasource testing) with used credentials? Used test SQL query can be a problem for your DB.

Comment: Yes, when I used PSQL outside of Grafana with given creds it all worked well.